# "for each" or "every" keywords in Scheme

Tags: loops, scheme, racket

Is there a `for` loop or `for each` loop in Scheme ?

I've been searching around and found there is a keyword "`every`" but the scheme compiler language I'm using does not have this function pre-build in. This is what it suppose to do, it can be find [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch8/higher.html)

```
(define (first-letters sent)
  (every first sent))

> (first-letters '(here comes the sun))
(H C T S)
```

How can I re-write the `every` function ? using other pre-defined function. The language I'm using is in the DrScheme - Essentials of Programming Languages (3rd ed)

I tried all the pre-installed compiler in DrScheme none of them can compile the `every` function.

Any ideas ?

Comment: As Toms says (but the link is a really bad place for an explanation) `map` is the function you're describing.  Note also that your code assumes some `first` function that can accept a symbol and return a symbol holding only the first character -- and that's not something that is very common.  (At least not outside of Berkley and the Simply Scheme textbook.)

Comment: i think for first I can easily use car to implement yea the map is not something I was looking for.

Comment: Scheme does not have "keywords".

Comment: @Svante Not in the sense of predefined language construct. Most scheme implementation have keywords (that is, self-evaluating symbols).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for `map`, although you probably would like to know that Scheme also has `for-each`. `map` does exactly what you want with `every`. It does something to each item in the list, returning a new list of the results.

You could even say

```
(define every map)
```

You can get your `first` function by writing

```
(define (first symbol)
  (string->symbol (string (string-ref (symbol->string symbol) 0))))
```

This is bad Scheme style, though. It looks like ancient Lisp from the 60s or 70s, back before strings were in the language.
Anyway, Now you can say

```
(map first '(here comes everybody))
=> (h c e)
```

---

`for-each` does some kind of side effect to each item in the list:

```
(define initials (map first '(here comes everybody)))
(for-each display initials)
=> hce
```

Comment: The definition of `first` would be slightly better as `(string->symbol (substring (symbol->string symbol) 0 1))`.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/projects/poplog/paradigms_lectures/lecture5.html#map_list) could be the answer of your question. Map function, takes a function and list(-s) as arguments, applies function to elements of list, returns the results.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addition to Nathan's post, which is the best answer for you right now...

If you ever move over to the `scheme` or `scheme/base` module languages, you will gain access to PLT's army of `for` iterators. These look a bit more like the "for each" loops that are common in other languages. Search for `for` in the docs:

```
(define (first symbol)
  (string->symbol (string (string-ref (symbol->string symbol) 0))))

(for/list ([symbol (in-list '(here comes everybody))])
  (first symbol))

=> '(h c e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends which Scheme you're looking at. Apart from "for-each" and "map" mentioned above (which are part of the various standards, hence present in all real Schemes), you can find impelementation-specific extensions.  For example, PLT scheme has a whole slew of such forms, which you can read about [here](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/guide/for.html).